# find PI number using integers based on string

Tags: c++, pi, bigint

something does not work as expected, please give me a piece of advice.
I try to find the PI number with many decimals, I user with success the atan series
but I try to use a faster method and it seems that Chudnovsky is one of the solution.
But after some tests it seems that something went wrongly, more exactly there are 
just a few exact decimals.

```
#include "bigInt.h"

#define DECIMALS 200

Bint ONE_() {
    string one("1");
    for (int i = 1; i <= DECIMALS; i++)
        one = one + "0";
    return Bint(one.c_str());
}

Bint FOUR_() {
    string four("4");
    for (int i = 1; i <= DECIMALS; i++)
        four = four + "0";
    return Bint(four.c_str());
}

Bint EIGHT_() {
    string eight("8");
    for (int i = 1; i <= DECIMALS; i++)
        eight = eight + "0";
    return Bint(eight.c_str());
}

static Bint ONE, FOUR, EIGHT;

class Init {
public:
    Init() {
        ONE = ONE_();
        FOUR = FOUR_();
        EIGHT = EIGHT_();
    }
};
..............

Bint Chudnovsky() {
    Bint SQR("10002499687578100594479218787636");
    Bint C("426880");
    Bint L("13591409");
    Bint LS("545140134");
    Bint X("1");
    Bint M("1");
    Bint B("-262537412640768000");
    Bint PI(L);
    Bint K("6");
    int i = 1;

    while(i < 100) {
        M = M * (K * K * K -  K * 16) / (i + 1) / (i + 1) / (i++ + 1);
        L = L + LS;
        X = X * B;
        PI = PI + M * L / X;
        K = K + 12;
    }

    PI = ONE / PI;
    PI = C *SQR * PI;
    return PI;
}

.....................

main()
{
    cout << "START ------------------------------" << endl;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    Bint PI = Chudnovsky();

    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;

    cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " s" << endl;
    cout << " Chudnovsky formula" << endl;
    cout << endl << PI << endl << endl;

.................

}

START ------------------------------
Elapsed time: 21.3608 s
 Chudnovsky formula

31415926535897342076684535915783681294558937929099183167837859930489914621802640182485862944746935361889264019646528185561923712250878477720742566131296615384026777503347886889431404794013630226633347235010074370488851025463587840
```

Comment: What is `Bint`?

Comment: Also, please post a [mcve].  What is `ONE`?

Comment: https://github.com/maemual/BigInt

Comment: START ------------------------------
Elapsed time: 36.9005 s
 Chudnovsky formula

31415926535897342076684535915783681294558937929099183167837859930489914621802640182485862944746935361889264019646528185561923712250878477720742566131296615384026777503347886889431404794013630226633347235010074370488851025463587840

Comment: ONE is a BigInt with the most left digit equls with 1 and after this there are 200 of "0"

Comment: Place code in the original post, not in the comment section.

Comment: `(i + 1) / (i + 1) / (i++ + 1);` move `i++` to a separate line.

Comment: there is used a square root and I used just an approximation, I try to use also more decimals for it, maybe PI will be better evaluated.

Comment: I generate sqrt 10005 with 1000 decimals using Python getcontext().prec = 1000 and I used this value, but the result is still inconclusive: 
31415926535897342076684535915782983407622332609157065908941454987376662094016591080661173474 ......